# Docker-Compose mounting volume files on Mac but not PC

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to mount run a docker image with php:7.0-apache and mount my files to /var/www/html. When I run docker-compose up everything builds fine. When I visit localhost:8080 on a mac I am able to view the site as it should appear. When I visit on windows it says 403 forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.25 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8080. Please help I need this to run on windows machine.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  web: 
    container_name: ves-corporate-site
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./.docker/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./dist:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

# Run Linux apt (Advanced Package Tool) to and install any packages
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
# Enable mod_rewrite in apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite
```

**File structure**

```
/
  .docker/
      Dockerfile
  dist/
      index.php
      (many-other .php files)
  docker-compose.yml
```

No files are mounted in /var/www/html when I use docker-compose exec web bash to check them.

```
docker-compose exec web bash
ls
```

On a Mac I see my full working directory though.

Diving in further I have found my apache2.conf in my container at

etc/apache2/apache2.conf

In it I found this. This make sense to why it won't let me mount my files right? However When I update it to allow me I am unsure of next steps. How to I restart apache and the container while keeping my changes to allow me write to to /var/www/html. In some dire need of instruction, please help thanks.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLink
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow, deny
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time experimenting I discovers that the files weren't' being mounted form my docker-compose file. By following these steps I was able to fix the issue and was able to mount files again.

1. Open Docker settings from the system tray
2. Select Shared Drives
3. Un-select C drive and apply
4. Re-select C drive and apply